# Fastest way to add an extra row to a groupby in pandas

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I'm trying to create a new row for each group in a dataframe by copying the last row and then modifying some values. My approach is as follows, the concat step appears to be the bottleneck (I tried append too). Any suggestions?

```
def genNewObs(df):
    lastRowIndex = df.obsNumber.idxmax()
    row = pd.DataFrame(df.ix[lastRowIndex].copy())
    # changes some other values in row here
    df = pd.concat([df,row], ignore_index=True)
    return df

df = df.groupby(GROUP).apply(genNewObs)
```

Edit 1: Basically I have a bunch of data with the last observation on different dates. I want to create a final observation for all groups on the current date.

```
Group   Date       Days Since last Observation
  A    1/1/2014               0
  A    1/10/2014              9
  B    1/5/2014               0
  B    1/25/2014              20
  B    1/27/2014              2
```

If we pretend the current date is 1/31/2014 this becomes:

```
Group   Date       Days Since last Observation
  A    1/1/2014               0
  A    1/10/2014              9
  A    1/31/2014              21
  B    1/5/2014               0
  B    1/25/2014              20
  B    1/27/2014              2
  B    1/31/2014              4
```

I've tried setting with enlargement and it is the slowest of all techniques. Any ideas?

Comment: Why you need to append a new row after a data frame?

Comment: Because I need to create an observation for each of the groups in the dataframe.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here, can't you just do `df.loc[g.idxmax()]` ?

Comment: df.groupby('group').last() should give you the last row of each group.  You should be able to modify and concat once for all groups

Comment: Great idea. Trying it. For some reason pandas is dropping the Group column from the extracted rows.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user1827356, I sped it up by a factor of 100 by taking the operation out of the apply. For some reason first was dropping by Group column, so I used idxmax instead.

```
def genNewObs(df):
    lastRowIndex = df.groupby(Group).Date.idxmax()
    rows = df.ix[lastRowIndex]
    df = pd.concat([df,rows], ignore_index=True)
    df = df.sort([Group, Date], ascending=True)
    return df
```